# How to do Conditional Serialization using C# - NewtonSoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, jsonserializer

I am doing json serialization using NewtonSoft.Json

```
public class CommonBase
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "u_customer_id")]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to do a conditional serialization so that if `CustomerId` value is 0, I want to set a blank value for `CustomerId` during json serialization. Since `CommonBase` is a base class and I am not able to change data type from `long` to `string`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can write your own custom custom serializer. Example here: http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization . You need to implement `WriteJson` and `ReadJson` methods

Comment: @xszaboj..i don't prefer that..I just checking whetherJson.Net provide any built in feature for this or any workaround

Comment: What is your expected result? *"u_customer_id":null* or *"u_customer_id":""* or skip that property on serialization?

Comment: expected result is "u_customer_id":""

Comment: So the json property is sometimes string (when empty) and sometimes numeric (if not empty). That is a very bad design for a contract. Who was responsible for that? Please check in the contract description if u_customer_id is meant to be a string in all cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing CustomerId property as nullable.

```
   public long? CustomerId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost have the answer in your question title. What you are looking for is [Conditional Property Serialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm)

You just need to add method named like this: `ShouldSerialize + PropertyName`. In your case method should look like:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeCustomerId()
{
   return SomeCondition;
}
```

P.s. if you are creating base class, you probably want to have abstract class.