# Skip processing for a large property while serializing

Tags: .net-core, json.net

I have a class that one of its properties represents a base64 string of a file, I already have this file converted, the class look like this:

```
public class DocumentAddDto
{
    [Required]
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(DisplayNames.ExpirationDate)]
    public DateTime? ExpirationDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FileContent { get; set; }
}
```

I need to serialize this class and make a request to and API, I'm using HttpClient.SendAsync, the problem is that JsonConvert.SerializeObject its taking 2 seconds to serialize the object.

Is there an attribute where I can just use the serialization settings to create the property but not parse the value and just pass it through?

Comment: You could use [conditional property serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42781725/3744182) to conditionally serialize `FileContent`.  But I don't really understand what you mean by *Is there an attribute where the serialization just convert FileContent to camelCase but does not try to serialize the value and just pass it to the string*  Can you clarify what JSON you want to see in such a case?

Comment: edited the question to make it clear

Comment: But then you'll be creating badly-formed JSON, because characters in the `FileContent` that need to be escaped during serialization won't get escaped.

Comment: i forget about that, you are correct.